Two inept agents with an accent listen to classical music while driving
I recall watching a movie that would have been made in the 80's or 90's that involved two male agents who wore black suits, had a foreign accent, and were operating in the United States. The pair were basically inept clumsy idiots and I recall one of them frequently slapping the other and calling him an idiot. I believe they were looking for a person for some reason that I cannot recall, and would listen to classical music while driving. I recall them being criminals as well. The would have been live action, and most likely made in the United States, or Canada. Unfortunately, I don't recall what kind of accent the agents had. 
It's not either of the following:

The Invisible Man
Return of the Living Dead: Rave to the Grave
Chitty Chitty Bang Bang
Lionheart


This is never the blues brothers is it? tallies up on the two black suites.  it might be said that they've unusual accents?

@AidanO, no. I'm becoming more and more convinced I'm just delusional.

Not the Thompsons from Tintin?

@KaushikGhose No. Never seen it.

Some of the details sound similar to Spies Like Us

Although the foreign accents don't match here, and I'm not sure about the classical music either, I'm thinking of Pulp Fiction. Check this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Pkq_eBHXJ4

Did any of the current answers correctly get the film?

@AndrewMartin, No, unfortunately not.

It sounds like the Jean Claude Van Damme movie, Wrong Bet, aka Lionheart, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionheart_(1990_film) in that the hero escapes from the Foreign Legion in order to track down his brothers murderer, he is relentlessly pursued by two French M.P's who are quite inept and humorous, although they are nothing to be sneezed at. 

This seems promising. I'm certain I remember that poster. I'll watch the trailer when I get home and find out for sure.

The two aren't really in it much, it is mostly about the hero fighting in illegal street fights, but I think I remember them listening to classical music, and one of them was somewhat dumber than the other and was slapped around by him.

With what you've given us, I know this sounds a bit far fetched, but could you be thinking of "Chitty, Chitty, Bang, Bang"?
Reason being, the inventor father in the movie tells his kids a story about a evil ruler of a far off land who wants to steal the amazing car (Chitty) that the father built.  After the father escapes with his family and the car, the evil ruler sends two hopeless spies after them.  They are dressed in black and have ridiculous accents.  The thin one is always ordering the fat one around and belittling him (calling him a fool and idiot and so on).  There is also one scene when they steal a car and pretend to be posh English people driving to the inventors house.  They end up kidnapping the inventors father instead of the inventor.
Could this possibly be it?

I don't think so, nothing about that movie looks familiar.

My favorite part of that movie is that Benny Hill, whose sketch-comedy show was rather risque and full of mostly-undressed women, played a toymaker that helped the children.
